# feeds_ex module tests returns me fatal error

Tags: 7, feeds, testing

When I am running feeds_ex test i got an error that says:

```
PHP Fatal error: Class 'TUnit' not found in /sites/all/modules/contrib/feeds_ex/src/Tests/FeedsExUnitTests.test on line 11
```

I am looking around in google and forums but nothing similar found.

Any solution appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [instructions for the Feeds extensible parsers module](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_ex):

> To run tests locally, the TUnit module is required.

So you need to install the [TUnit](https://www.drupal.org/project/tunit) module, which contains the missing class.